# date countdown in dart

Tags: dart, flutter

am trying to create a countdown on specific date i have and display how many hours, minutes and seconds left until then ..

for example i want to set the counter date to: Thursday, October 25, 2018 7:14:05 AM

and i want to display for the user.. remaining time: hh:mm:ss till 25 october ...

i tried this:

```
@override
void initState() {

new CountdownTimer(new Duration(milliseconds: 1540451645), new Duration(seconds: 1)).listen((data) {
  print('Remaining time: ${data.remaining.inSeconds}');
  print(new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch);
  print(DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(data.remaining.inSeconds));
  var format = new DateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
  var dateString = format.format(DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(data.remaining.inSeconds));
  print(dateString);
});
super.initState();
}
```

but the result is: 03:25:40.. which is really not true ...

how to do this?

Comment: Updated answer - added working code for show countdown timer

Comment: Did you checked your code? Found the problem?

Comment: @AndreyTurkovsky still didn't try your updated answer .. will try it and let you know

Comment: So, it's more than month passed. I don't understand the reason to ask question when you don't need the answer. Is it so hard to just copy-paste code for checking?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all - there is error: you have to use `data.remaining.inMilliseconds` instead of `data.remaining.inSeconds`

For formatting it'll be better to use Duration instead of DateTime. But you can change your existing code like:

```
var format = new DateFormat("mm:ss");
var dateString = '${data.remaining.inHours}:${format.format(DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(data.remaining.inMilliseconds))};
print(dateString);
```

**UPD**
Widget for showing remaining time

```
int estimateTs = DateTime(2018, 11, 5, 7, 15, 30).millisecondsSinceEpoch; // set needed date

....

StreamBuilder(
                      stream: Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (i) => i),
                      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<int> snapshot) {
                        DateFormat format = DateFormat("mm:ss");
                        int now = DateTime
                            .now()
                            .millisecondsSinceEpoch;
                        Duration remaining = Duration(milliseconds: estimateTs - now);
                        var dateString = '${remaining.inHours}:${format.format(
                            DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(remaining.inMilliseconds))}';
                        print(dateString);
                        return Container(color: Colors.greenAccent.withOpacity(0.3),
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: Text(dateString),);
                      });
```

Comment: tried it and got: 427:54:07.. which means 427 hours left? and 54 minutes?

Comment: Yes. I've thought this is what you wanted

Comment: yes this exactly what i want .. but from today to 25 cot is only 2 days away .. 427 is really huge number?

Comment: So, check your code. What is `1540451645`? Where do you set Oct 25th as end of timer?

Comment: 1540451645  this is my end time

Comment: DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(1540451645) - this is 1970 Jan 18. Try Duration(seconds: 1540451645) instead

Comment: am sure that 25 oct 2018 Timestamp in seconds is 1540463571.. yet am getting 427906:32:44 !

Comment: What returns this string `print('Remaining time: ${data.remaining.inSeconds}');`?

Comment: Remaining time: 1540463565

Comment: So, how can it be? 1540463565 seconds - it's 17829 days. And it is exactly 427906 hours, so my solution works. Check your code

Comment: sorry for being this late ... i just tried the code .. i have set the date to:   int estimateTs = DateTime(2018, 12, 14, 7, 15, 30).millisecondsSinceEpoch;
 and the result is: 236:26:38 .. what does this mean?!

Comment: Estimate date is Dec 14 2018, 07:15:30 and result shows you haw many time is left to this date and time. Isn't this you asked about?

Comment: 236 is what? hours?

Comment: Yes. 236 hours, 26 min and 38 sec

Comment: yes this exactly what i wanted! thank you so much :)

Comment: but how to convert it to: days hours:minutes:seconds?

Comment: You asked "remaining time: hh:mm:ss", you didn't speak of day. Change `"mm:ss"` to `"hh:mm:ss"` and `inHours` to `inDays`

Answer (score 1):

Do you know Joha ? you made complex code joha is making complex things ,

Use this function :

```
var timeleft = TimeNow.difference(nextday);
```

This function will give you time left from 2 DateTime .

Comment: this is genius, we just need to set state and let `Datetime.now()` to decrease by its own