# When i get the difference between endDate.millisecondsSinceEpoch and startDate.millisecondsSinceEpoch it gives me the result plus 2 hours?

Tags: datetime, dart, flutter, duration

**I want to get the difference between `endDate` and `startDate`**

`int endDate = DateTime.parse("2019-01-31 09:35:00").millisecondsSinceEpoch;`

`int startDate = DateTime.parse("2019-01-31 09:30:00").millisecondsSinceEpoch;`

**Then i get the diffrernce**

`int distance = endDate - startDate;`

**After that i convert distance to DateTime**

`DateTime newTime = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(distance);`

**Result**

```
 02:05:00
```

**Expected Output**

```
00:05:00
```

[image]

**Where is the mistake ?**

Comment: Maybe it something with `locae`. Anyway - why do you use `fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch`, I think in your case you need `Duration`, not `DateTime`

Comment: I need DateTime to get hours, minutes, seconds to use them in a countdown timer , but duration give me inHours, inMinutes , inSeconds

Comment: Here's example of countdown timer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52945049/7130820

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Date/Time calculations in local timezone are prone to mistakes.
Convert to UTC first:

```
  int endDate =
      DateTime.parse("2019-01-31 09:35:00").toUtc().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
  int startDate =
      DateTime.parse("2019-01-31 09:30:00").toUtc().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
  int distance = endDate - startDate;

  DateTime newTime = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(distance, isUtc: true);
  print('result: $newTime');
```

> result: 1970-01-01 00:05:00.000Z

But as mentioned in the comment below your question, `Duration` would be better for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Try this very simple package, [Jiffy](https://pub.dev/packages/jiffy) that is inspired by [momentjs](https://momentjs.com)

Looks like you are trying to get the difference in minutes. See below

```
var startDate = Jiffy(DateTime(2019, 1, 31, 9, 35));
var endDate = Jiffy(DateTime(2019, 1, 31, 9, 30));

print(startDate.diff(endDate, Units.MINUTE)); // 5 minutes
```

You can also get the difference in the following units, years, months, weeks, days, hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds. Also, see below

```
print(startDate.diff(endDate, Units.SECOND)); // 300 seconds
print(startDate.diff(endDate, Units.MILLISECOND)); // 300000 milliseconds
```